# How to handle multiple concurrent chat windows in Android?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper that contains multiple chat windows at any given time.  When I click a user A on my contact list and open a chat with that user A, the ViewFlipper is brought into the foreground and I'm able to start a chat with user A.  If I want to then open another, concurrent chat with user B, I must press the back button on the android device, be brought back to the contact list and click on another user.

When this happens, as soon as I click on User B, the previous chat from User A is deleted since the onCreate() method was called in the ViewFlipper Activity.

How can I avoid this problem?  I would like to click on User B and have it *added* to the ViewFlipper instead of the ViewFlipper resetting itself.

Do I have to put the ViewFlipper as a Service? Is there something I can do in the onPause, onResume, or maybe reprogram the onBackPressed method?

The contact screen is implemented as follows:

**list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/no_friend" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**contact_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_width="48dip"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**contact.java**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            View v = 
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(friends[position].userName);
        if (friends[position].status == STATUS.NEW_MSG)
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mNewMsgIcon);
        if (friends[position].status == STATUS.OPEN)
            holder.icon.setImageBitmap(mOpenChat);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Where mInflater is

```
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

The ListAdapter is defined within contact.java (it would take up the entire screen if I put it here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the back button onDestroy() for the view flipper Activity will be called and so your previous session is deleted. Why not give the user an option to select the chat options from the view flipper Activity itself so the session will be retained and you could just flip the views...

Comment: So that would be adding the Contacts screen to the first index of the ViewFlipper? Then the user can always have the Contacts screen + any open chats.

Comment: Yes... You could also give an option like when a user presses a button or menu you could show the contact list.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I have that functionality in an Action Bar, one less thing to take care of now.  Now, only to figure out how to edit that contacts screen while it lives in the ViewFlipper.

Comment: can you explain a bit on how you have implemented the contact screen?

Comment: I see you are using list view for your contacts, so to update it you have to change the "friends[]" array accordingly and calling notifyDataSetChanged() to update the listview...